# Replace certain phrase with another certain phrase

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am just trying to replace a certain phrase / word with a unicode character in javascript / jQuery.

I've tried the below and some other solution, but nothing seems to be working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav li a").html(function(i, currentHtml) {
          switch(currentHtml){
            case "About":
            return "&#xe00f;";

            case "Work":
            return "&#xe010;";

                case "CV":
                    return "&#xe00c;";

            case "Resume":
            return "&#xe00e;";

                case "down":
                    return "&#xe00d;";

            case "Mail":
            return "&#xe011;";

            case "Dribbble":
            return "&#xe015;";

            case "GooglePlus":
             return "&#xe012;";

            case "Facebook":
             return "&#xe013;";

            case "Twitter":
             return "&#xe014;";

                default:
             return currentHtml;
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it failing because of case?  You could .toLowerCase() your input and change your cases to all be lower case.  Also, what value do you get if you alert(currentHtml)?

Comment: No, text is in exactly that case / form in the site this is running in. None of them are replaced.

Comment: I get nothing just a blank alert.

Comment: Then you are probably addressing the a tag incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but only for the first replacement.

You need to use :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = $(".nav li a").html();

    text = text.replace(/About/g,'&#xe00f;');
    text = text.replace(/Work/g,'&#xe010;');
    ....

    $(".nav li a").html(text);
});
```

**Code updated**

Comment: ah, that makes sense. But it is not working. I checked in developer tools and the words have not changed. jQuery is loaded.

Comment: It is working now. Except, all text in .nav li a is replaced with the text only About should be replaced with ( &#xe00f; ).

Comment: Thank You. Although it still replaces everything with &#xe00f; Here is the code I am using: https://gist.github.com/theirf/5332511

Answer (score -1):

you missing one }.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav li a").html(function(i, currentHtml) {
          switch(currentHtml){
            ......
          default:
             return currentHtml;
         **}**
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried it in IE, it doesnot work at all. but in FireFox, it works well.